# Предлагаю объединить метки "топонимы" и "топономика"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки

Существенна ли разница между метками "топонимы" и "топономика"? Полезно ли держать обе метки? Думаю, это вносит только путаницу. Предлагаю объединить метки [топонимы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b) и [топономика](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я объединил метки и создал синонимы. Спасибо за предложение!